# Expresso Store - Order conformation email not sending

Tags: expresso-store, devdemon, expresso

We're using EE 2.9 and Expresso Store 2.3.1. We've set up an Order Conformation email template, but no matter what we put in the To or BCC fields, no email is sent to the client.  We can send email ok from Tools > Communicate and other emails from the site are sending ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved now, Sendmail wasn't working, but switching to PHP Mail is.